# Symfony - Sonata admin - override validation

Tags: symfony, sonata

i'm using sonata admin, i tried to override max length allowed for name of categorie

I have an entity MyEntity who extend `Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category`

// MyEntity admin class

I put this following function, regarding https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/conditional_validation.html#inline-validation

```
public function validate(\Sonata\Form\Validator\ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
{
    parent::validate($errorElement, $object);

    $errorElement->with('name')
            ->assertLength(['max' => 100])
    ;
}
```

[Current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Rs3.png)

Expected to get ride of this 32 max length on name's field

Thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need to do instead, is override this validation config: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataClassificationBundle/blob/3.x/src/Resources/config/validation.xml

```
<class name="Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Model\Category">
    <property name="name">
        <constraint name="NotBlank"/>
        <constraint name="Length">
            <option name="min">2</option>
            <option name="max">32</option>
        </constraint>
    </property>
</class>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I tried to create this xml file from my extend bundle: 
located into : Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Resources\Config\validation.xml

but no effect

Comment: Hi, no one have implement this ?